# Redirect dynamic URL of travel website using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect

```
tour.php?translit=golden-triangle-of-india-with-ranthambore
```

to

```
tour/golden-triangle-of-india-with-ranthambore.html
```

using `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^translit=(golden-triangle-of-india-with-ranthambore)$
RewriteRule ^(tour)\.php$ /$1/%1.html? [R,L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the parenthesised subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, and `%1` is a backreference to the parenthesised subpattern in the last matched *CondPattern*. This is simply to avoid repetition in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

The trailing `?` on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* removes the query string from the request that would otherwise be passed through to the substitution (target URL).

This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change `R` to `R=301` if this is intended to be permanent, but only after you have confirmed it is working OK (since 301s are cached hard by the browser).

Comment: I've updated my answer. A trailing `?` on the RewriteRule substitution is required in order to remove the query string from the request. (Sorry, just forgot about that!)

Comment: The url is properly rewritten but I am getting 404 error.

May be I need a second line something like this
RewriteRule ^aboutus\.php$ /aboutus.html [R=301]
RewriteRule ^aboutus.html$ /aboutus.php [L]
(aboutus.html is working)

Comment: Does a direct request for `/tour/golden-triangle-of-india-with-ranthambore.html` work? Or does that also result in a 404? In your question you (only) asked about redirecting from A to B - which is what my answer addresses. But by the sounds of it you may be wanting to implement "pretty" URLs on your site?